# RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp when using curve_fit

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I’m attempting to fit a curve to time series data, X axis being the number of days elapsed and Y is the corresponding value. There are 2411 days total in the dataset, but when I try and curve fit to the entire dataset, I get the errors `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp`, `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square`, and `OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated`.

After reading a few of the solutions here, I came to the conclusion that the values returned from `np.exp()` must have been too large, so I used `sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()`, but there was no change.

Through some trial and error I discovered that if I pass only the first 355 values the cell runs without error, but on the 356th value the errors start, with the exp error first showing on the 711th value. Here is the relevant code including the first 711 elements:

```
def func0(x,a,b,c):
    return a * np.exp(b*x) + c

yData = np.array([0.00765047, 0.00791042, 0.00870343, 0.00819011, 0.00806836,
       0.00780183, 0.00768995, 0.0076044 , 0.00808153, 0.00914107,
       0.00996371, 0.00852246, 0.00690681, 0.00541291, 0.00522535,
       0.00517599, 0.00474494, 0.00772615, 0.00334646, 0.00285288,
       0.00366564, 0.0041329 , 0.00419213, 0.00492262, 0.00508715,
       0.00726877, 0.00800584, 0.00830528, 0.0093056 , 0.00969059,
       0.00923321, 0.00844019, 0.00881531, 0.00840071, 0.00640007,
       0.00516941, 0.0055215 , 0.00535368, 0.00405393, 0.00278707,
       0.00363603, 0.0038894 , 0.00352086, 0.00266861, 0.00194799,
       0.00265874, 0.0017012 , 0.00233627, 0.00189534, 0.00135241,
       0.00122737, 0.        , 0.00027969, 0.00116814, 0.00053636,
       0.00143138, 0.0033333 , 0.00329381, 0.00275746, 0.00449156,
       0.00607102, 0.00630464, 0.00630464, 0.00722928, 0.00800255,
       0.00717005, 0.00787751, 0.0078117 , 0.00759124, 0.00641981,
       0.0070154 , 0.00686074, 0.00626516, 0.00571564, 0.00587358,
       0.0075353 , 0.00819998, 0.00804533, 0.00701869, 0.01173401,
       0.01122069, 0.01146418, 0.01323449, 0.01233288, 0.01283304,
       0.01189195, 0.01205319, 0.01310616, 0.01413938, 0.01428416,
       0.01484026, 0.01368529, 0.01037831, 0.01113513, 0.01188537,
       0.01244805, 0.01239869, 0.0115991 , 0.01062839, 0.01029605,
       0.01119765, 0.01091138, 0.01175375, 0.01034212, 0.01075343,
       0.00899958, 0.00813417, 0.00874621, 0.00891074, 0.00944709,
       0.00841058, 0.00833161, 0.00953923, 0.0082296 , 0.00746291,
       0.00835793, 0.00880215, 0.01094428, 0.01008875, 0.01092125,
       0.01039147, 0.01325423, 0.01361619, 0.01421835, 0.01432036,
       0.01596562, 0.01718311, 0.01751217, 0.01835125, 0.01885799,
       0.01697252, 0.01653817, 0.01728512, 0.01625848, 0.01707782,
       0.01663689, 0.0187856 , 0.01795968, 0.0171897 , 0.01827886,
       0.01728183, 0.01750888, 0.02025317, 0.02070727, 0.02025317,
       0.01985831, 0.01669283, 0.01612028, 0.01332991, 0.01373136,
       0.01076988, 0.01451779, 0.01091138, 0.01230327, 0.01359973,
       0.01381362, 0.01207951, 0.01150367, 0.00709108, 0.00590978,
       0.0054524 , 0.01072053, 0.01077976, 0.01022037, 0.01260271,
       0.01499163, 0.01643617, 0.01785438, 0.01696923, 0.01613344,
       0.01816698, 0.01939106, 0.01852236, 0.01659082, 0.01829202,
       0.01926931, 0.02026963, 0.02165494, 0.02577467, 0.02656111,
       0.0237839 , 0.02332981, 0.0204868 , 0.02061184, 0.02266513,
       0.02080927, 0.02261906, 0.02022685, 0.01818343, 0.01678496,
       0.01695607, 0.01925943, 0.01992083, 0.02098367, 0.02314883,
       0.02451769, 0.02495533, 0.02473816, 0.02821295, 0.0267717 ,
       0.02728173, 0.02321793, 0.02390236, 0.02428735, 0.02521857,
       0.02177669, 0.01231643, 0.01507389, 0.0185421 , 0.01728841,
       0.01682445, 0.01798271, 0.01886128, 0.0182657 , 0.0184368 ,
       0.01876257, 0.01653488, 0.01639339, 0.01856513, 0.01907187,
       0.01870992, 0.01678825, 0.01433023, 0.01190182, 0.0093056 ,
       0.01032237, 0.00922005, 0.00705159, 0.01091796, 0.00902262,
       0.01030592, 0.01189853, 0.01153658, 0.01160568, 0.0102072 ,
       0.01130295, 0.00971034, 0.01054942, 0.00939444, 0.00642968,
       0.00633097, 0.00667647, 0.00667647, 0.0060414 , 0.00709108,
       0.00440272, 0.00594269, 0.00536684, 0.0050345 , 0.00425136,
       0.00424148, 0.00399141, 0.00594269, 0.00544253, 0.00547543,
       0.00712069, 0.00578803, 0.00604469, 0.00589991, 0.00492262,
       0.00574196, 0.00680809, 0.00936812, 0.01101667, 0.00985841,
       0.0082658 , 0.00856523, 0.00882847, 0.01064484, 0.0113194 ,
       0.01025985, 0.01101338, 0.00608418, 0.00682784, 0.00878899,
       0.00729509, 0.0076406 , 0.00806507, 0.00790055, 0.00808482,
       0.01007558, 0.00998016, 0.00773273, 0.00623883, 0.0070845 ,
       0.00700552, 0.00645272, 0.00589662, 0.00597559, 0.00577816,
       0.00751227, 0.00615986, 0.00627503, 0.00603153, 0.00634742,
       0.00662053, 0.00750239, 0.00877583, 0.00768337, 0.00737735,
       0.00777222, 0.00700552, 0.00771957, 0.00792358, 0.00807824,
       0.01031908, 0.01012165, 0.01034212, 0.01121081, 0.01378729,
       0.01463296, 0.01322461, 0.01435985, 0.01366884, 0.01220126,
       0.01273104, 0.01086531, 0.01099693, 0.01016772, 0.00855865,
       0.00888441, 0.00977944, 0.00904565, 0.00807165, 0.00902262,
       0.00990448, 0.00991435, 0.00954581, 0.00897326, 0.00966098,
       0.0110068 , 0.01152341, 0.02167797, 0.02333968, 0.02272765,
       0.02279675, 0.02253351, 0.02073688, 0.02112187, 0.02070727,
       0.02040454, 0.02162532, 0.02195108, 0.02038808, 0.0208685 ,
       0.02075991, 0.01888432, 0.01740029, 0.01880205, 0.01788729,
       0.01852894, 0.01785767, 0.0170844 , 0.01769644, 0.01588007,
       0.01709098, 0.01554772, 0.01763721, 0.0171897 , 0.0186474 ,
       0.0190291 , 0.0189238 , 0.01827228, 0.01824595, 0.01768985,
       0.01759772, 0.01888102, 0.02029924, 0.02075004, 0.0204177 ,
       0.01961152, 0.02013471, 0.01944699, 0.02126994, 0.02127324,
       0.01985502, 0.02217155, 0.02249073, 0.02255983, 0.02174707,
       0.02108568, 0.02108568, 0.01925943, 0.01888761, 0.01789716,
       0.01889419, 0.01811104, 0.01841377, 0.01859146, 0.02145421,
       0.02215181, 0.02140157, 0.02042428, 0.01845326, 0.01942725,
       0.02512315, 0.02471841, 0.02380036, 0.0234022 , 0.02298102,
       0.02434987, 0.0240274 , 0.02487307, 0.02415573, 0.02405044,
       0.02361938, 0.02351737, 0.02376416, 0.02515605, 0.02651504,
       0.02639   , 0.02612018, 0.02582403, 0.02702507, 0.02639987,
       0.02789377, 0.02729489, 0.02801552, 0.02834786, 0.02805171,
       0.02872627, 0.02859794, 0.02805171, 0.02974962, 0.03230307,
       0.03162851, 0.03116126, 0.0311481 , 0.03266503, 0.03300395,
       0.03192795, 0.03217474, 0.03313886, 0.03285259, 0.03175355,
       0.03087498, 0.030105  , 0.02918694, 0.03146399, 0.03071704,
       0.02995693, 0.02949296, 0.03124352, 0.03274071, 0.03209577,
       0.03227675, 0.02961142, 0.02764698, 0.02739361, 0.02678157,
       0.02738045, 0.02730147, 0.02846961, 0.02760091, 0.02600501,
       0.0239583 , 0.0241327 , 0.02221762, 0.02038479, 0.02542588,
       0.02366545, 0.02341866, 0.02351079, 0.02413928, 0.02520212,
       0.02339233, 0.0218425 , 0.02150028, 0.02155293, 0.02159571,
       0.02039467, 0.01962139, 0.0211449 , 0.02261906, 0.0239583 ,
       0.02535678, 0.02596552, 0.02719618, 0.02712379, 0.02834457,
       0.02971343, 0.02997009, 0.02940412, 0.03011487, 0.03059858,
       0.03040444, 0.03037153, 0.02856175, 0.02952258, 0.02987466,
       0.02970685, 0.029029  , 0.03056567, 0.03271768, 0.03192466,
       0.03307963, 0.03157257, 0.03213196, 0.02884473, 0.02873943,
       0.0277095 , 0.02958181, 0.0317009 , 0.0320859 , 0.03230636,
       0.03536984, 0.03468541, 0.03467554, 0.0343432 , 0.03519873,
       0.03677489, 0.03650178, 0.03552449, 0.03603452, 0.03657417,
       0.0359391 , 0.03525467, 0.0370151 , 0.04048002, 0.03786406,
       0.03270122, 0.03678476, 0.03439584, 0.03423132, 0.03257947,
       0.03485323, 0.03331655, 0.03266174, 0.03322771, 0.031668  ,
       0.03215829, 0.03570218, 0.0356265 , 0.03426093, 0.03579432,
       0.03469528, 0.03454063, 0.03436952, 0.03254328, 0.03237546,
       0.03365548, 0.03399111, 0.03447482, 0.03689993, 0.03771598,
       0.03712369, 0.0371533 , 0.03725531, 0.0362846 , 0.03723557,
       0.03755475, 0.03447482, 0.03318493, 0.03189175, 0.03140476,
       0.03169103, 0.03041102, 0.03184569, 0.03127643, 0.03268806,
       0.03433003, 0.03472161, 0.03311583, 0.03367851, 0.03226687,
       0.03228333, 0.03109874, 0.03224055, 0.03296118, 0.03415564,
       0.03582722, 0.03682096, 0.03512634, 0.03664656, 0.03502104,
       0.03239521, 0.03269135, 0.03375419, 0.03551462, 0.03547514,
       0.03742313, 0.03087827, 0.02920998, 0.03054922, 0.02871311,
       0.03013462, 0.0319444 , 0.03117771, 0.03183911, 0.03215171,
       0.0326387 , 0.03378052, 0.03407008, 0.03532706, 0.03474464,
       0.03394175, 0.03584367, 0.03509672, 0.03550146, 0.03356005,
       0.03317835, 0.03315861, 0.03498485, 0.03440571, 0.03483348,
       0.03561334, 0.03484994, 0.03446165, 0.03494536, 0.03516254,
       0.03813717, 0.03951919, 0.03744945, 0.0364261 , 0.03778179,
       0.0371895 , 0.03852874, 0.03974623, 0.03856165, 0.03700852,
       0.03698219, 0.0360773 , 0.0365643 , 0.03836751, 0.03836092,
       0.03840699, 0.03985811, 0.04039447, 0.04049318, 0.04110193,
       0.04265177, 0.04296108, 0.04322432, 0.04563627, 0.0482325 ,
       0.04791002, 0.04800874, 0.04860761, 0.04710056, 0.04746909,
       0.04689325, 0.04609695, 0.04539935, 0.04686693, 0.04970007,
       0.04775537, 0.04654117, 0.04614959, 0.04758097, 0.04713346,
       0.04607391, 0.04599494, 0.04473138, 0.04434639, 0.04484655,
       0.04465899, 0.04376396, 0.04289856, 0.04129607, 0.04075314,
       0.04099992, 0.04150008, 0.04067087, 0.04236878, 0.04246092,
       0.04121052, 0.03947312, 0.03968701, 0.04047673, 0.03948957,
       0.04206276, 0.04365538, 0.04380674, 0.04438587, 0.04565272,
       0.04586661, 0.04562969, 0.04537303, 0.04506372, 0.04445168,
       0.0471203 , 0.04970665, 0.04971652, 0.05112487, 0.04952896,
       0.05039766, 0.04991066, 0.05171058, 0.05101628, 0.04990737,
       0.0526418 , 0.05249701, 0.05060496, 0.05201331, 0.04904855,
       0.04681099, 0.04516573, 0.04744935, 0.04933153, 0.04926901,
       0.04785409, 0.04919991, 0.04929204, 0.05526763, 0.05444829,
       0.05645551, 0.05455359, 0.05634693, 0.06660678, 0.06488584,
       0.06637973])
xData = np.array([*range(yData.shape[0])])

popt,pcov = curve_fit(func0, xData, yData)
```

The last value here isn't the highest, nor the lowest, in the list so why is it here that the error is being thrown?

Comment: `curve_fit` will set `p0` (the starting guess for the model parameters) to an array of ones. This probably isn’t close for your data / model. Try explicitly passing a better starting guess. I would try something like `p0=(1, 1e-3, 0)` because the main issue is that your exponent is blowing up.

Comment: That did the trick, @DavidHoffman, thanks!

Comment: Even better would be the scale factor in your fit function, such that all fit parameters vary on the order of 1.